# Radio Button and Checkbox don't update variable value

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have a GUI that uses a class that calls a function that provides a popup window.
The popup box has a button that gets a directory from the user using askdirectory() from tkinter.filedialog, a pair of radio buttons(RadioG, RadioY), and checkbox(state_checkbox) that I want to update the two different variables(driveletter and statevalue) . I've set the drive letter to "G:" and that value is held correctly, but doesn't update if I select the "Y:" Radio button. I have the IntVar.set(1), but that checkbox does not populate as checked and checking/unchecking it keeps the value at 1 and does not update it to 0 when unchecked.

Any advice on what I'm missing to keep my values from updating is appreciated.

relevant section of code below:

```
class preferences(Preferences):
    def save_preferences(self):
        # Used to reset the folder location desired by the user
        self.prefdialog = tk.Tk()
        self.prefdialog.title('Set Preferences')

        self.driveletter = tk.StringVar()
        self.driveletter.set("G:")
        self.statevalue = tk.IntVar()
        self.statevalue.set(1)
        self.fpath = '\\Desktop'

        self.RadioG = tk.Radiobutton(self.prefdialog, text="G:", variable=self.driveletter,
            value="G:", command=lambda: print(self.driveletter.get()))
        self.RadioG.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=tk.W,pady=4)

        self.RadioY = tk.Radiobutton(self.prefdialog, text="Y:", variable=self.driveletter,
            value="Y:", command=lambda: print(self.driveletter.get()))
        self.RadioY.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=tk.W,pady=4)

        self.state_checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(
            self.prefdialog, text="Check to use state folders",
            variable=self.statevalue, command=lambda: print(self.statevalue.get()))
        self.state_checkbox.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=tk.W,pady=4)

        self.prefdialog.mainloop()
```

For posterity: Looks like my issue was using Tk() twice. Per Bryan since I'm trying to create a popup window, I should be calling Toplevel(), not a second instance of Tk(). I also definitely called mainloop() twice, once for my main window and once for this popup window.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I had to remove all the references to nonexistent methods so the code would run. All the `print()` statements printed the correct checkbox or radio values.

Comment: It looks like your code may be using more than once instance of `Tk`. Is that what you're doing? If so, that's the root of the problem. Second and subsequent windows should be instances of `Toplevel`, and you shouldn't call `mainloop()` more than once in a program.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).